# How to property configure AWS CloudFormation template to run containers of Fargate?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, scrapy

I'm following [this](https://blog.vikfand.com/posts/scrapy-fargate-sls-guide/) excellent blog post on hosting a severless Scrapy application on AWS Fargate. Here's my tree structure thus far:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── fargate-template.yml
├── handler.py
├── launch_fargate.py
├── launcher.py
├── my_sls_scraper
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── requirements.txt
├── s3-template.yml
├── scrapy.cfg
└── serverless.yml
```

However, deploying using `sls deploy -v` gives me the following error: `Unable to resolve '3' log group name out of: {RetentionInDays: 1}`.

Here's the full error:

```
Serverless: Configuration warning:
Serverless:   at root: unrecognized property 'events'
Serverless:   at 'functions.pollSpidersScrape.events[0]': unsupported function event
Serverless:  
Serverless: Learn more about configuration validation here: http://slss.io/configuration-validation
Serverless:  
Serverless: Generated requirements from /Users/Desktop/scrapy-serverless/scraper/requirements.txt in /Users/Desktop/scrapy-serverless/scraper/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Using static cache of requirements found at /Users/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/c31122786e70934d64a78fc1a8e1e713bf397712d1d00d20399c3fe5907a73b4_slspyc ...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: serverless-cloudformation-sub-variables: Converting AWS CloudFormation Sub variables...
Serverless:  - 'arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}/*' => 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*'
Serverless:  - 'arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}' => 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}'
Serverless:  - 'fargate-#{StackName}' => 'fargate-${StackName}'
Serverless:  - 'arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}/*' => 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*'
Serverless:  - 'arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}/*' => 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*'
Serverless:  - 'arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}' => 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}'
Serverless:  - '#{AccountId}.dkr.ecr.#{Region}.amazonaws.com/#{Repo}' => '${AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${Region}.amazonaws.com/${Repo}'
Serverless:  - '#{AccountId}.dkr.ecr.#{Region}.amazonaws.com/#{Repo}' => '${AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${Region}.amazonaws.com/${Repo}'
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Unable to resolve '3' log group name out of: { RetentionInDays: 1 }
```

I assume that this error has to do with the configuration file, but I'm not sure what `Unable to resolve '3' log group` means. I'm quite sure the error originates from `fargate-template.yml`:

```
Resources:
  FargateECSCluster:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Sub
        - "fargate-#{StackName}"
        - StackName: !Ref "AWS::StackName"

  FargateLogGroup:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 1

  FargateTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Sid: "ECS"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ScraperFeedBucketPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: !Sub
                  - "arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}/*"
                  - BucketName: !Ref ScraperFeedBucket
        - PolicyName: HttpCacheBucketPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                  - "s3:ListBucket"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}/*"
                    - BucketName: !Ref HttpCacheBucket
                  - !Sub
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::#{BucketName}"
                    - BucketName: !Ref HttpCacheBucket

  FargateExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Sid: "ECS"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole

  FargateVPC:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.10.10.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
  FargateSubnet:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.10.10.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref FargateVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
  FargateIGW:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
  FargateAttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref FargateVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref FargateIGW
  FargateRouteTable:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref FargateVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
  FargateRoute:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
    DependsOn: FargateAttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref FargateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref FargateIGW
  FargateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref FargateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref FargateSubnet
  FargateSG:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Generated by Serverless"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      VpcId: !Ref FargateVPC

  FargateECSRepo:
    Type: "AWS::ECR::Repository"
    Properties:
      LifecyclePolicy:
        LifecyclePolicyText: |
          {
            "rules": [
            {
              "rulePriority": 1,
              "description": "Only keep 8 images",
              "selection": {
                "tagStatus": "any",
                "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
                "countNumber": 8
              },
              "action": { "type": "expire" }
            }]
          }

  FargateECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      Cpu: 512
      Memory: 1GB
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - "FARGATE"
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt FargateExecutionRole.Arn
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt FargateTaskRole.Arn
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: scraper_container
          Image: !Sub
            - "#{AccountId}.dkr.ecr.#{Region}.amazonaws.com/#{Repo}"
            - AccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
              Region: !Ref AWS::Region
              Repo: !Ref FargateECSRepo
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref FargateLogGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Ref AWS::StackName
Outputs:
  ECRRepo:
    Value: !Sub
      - "#{AccountId}.dkr.ecr.#{Region}.amazonaws.com/#{Repo}"
      - AccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        Region: !Ref AWS::Region
        Repo: !Ref FargateECSRepo
```

**How can I solve the above error?** Again, I suspect this is a config issue since running `docker build -t my_sls_scraper:latest .` and then `docker run my_sls_scraper` runs the scraper without a problem on my local machine.

**EDIT:**

Removing `FargateLogGroup` doesn't help since it returns the following error: `An error occurred: my-sls-scraper-dev - Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [FargateLogGroup] in the Resources block of the template.` That is, `FargateLogGroup` must be included in the `.yml`.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your answer as well if the issue is solved.

Comment: Ah good point - never did it before so slipped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding `LogGroupName: 'someName'` to `FargateLogGroup`:

```
  FargateLogGroup:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: 'someName'
      RetentionInDays: 1
```

This is a documentation issue since the CloudFormation [documentation][2] mentions that none of the fields are required.